# How to extract each JSON object in an array and feed into API request body

Tags: ruby, json, httparty

I have a array of 647 JSON objects and I want to extract each object and feed them one by one into the request body of an API. The API will only accept each JSON object separately with an individual HTTP request for each object. How do I do this?

This is what I have so far using a basic each block in Ruby with the HTTParty gem:

```
require "json"
require "httparty"

restaurants = JSON.parse File.read('pretty-regex2.json')

new_rest_variable = restaurants.each do |restaurant|
end

response = HTTParty.post("https://api.example/placeholder",
{
  :body => new_rest_variable.to_json,
  :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token example-placeholder" }
  })

puts response.body
puts response.code
puts response.message
```

Example of 4 "restaurant objects" enclosed in array square brackets from the 647:

```
[
  {
    "id": "223078",
    "name": "3 South Place",
    "phone": "+442032151270",
    "email": "3sp@southplacehotel.com",
    "website": "",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5190536,
      "longitude": -0.0871038,
      "address": {
        "line1": "3 South Place",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "EC2M 2AF",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "210071",
    "name": "5th View Bar & Food",
    "phone": "+442077347869",
    "email": "waterstones.piccadilly@elior.com",
    "website": "http://www.5thview.com",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5089594,
      "longitude": -0.1359897,
      "address": {
        "line1": "Waterstone's Piccadilly",
        "line2": "203-205 Piccadilly",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W1J 9HA",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "239971",
    "name": "65 & King",
    "phone": "+442072292233",
    "email": "hello@65king.com",
    "website": "http://www.65king.com/",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.5152533,
      "longitude": -0.1916538,
      "address": {
        "line1": "65 Westbourne Grove",
        "line2": "",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "W2 4UJ",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "131543",
    "name": "Abbey",
    "phone": "+442079682400",
    "email": "info@abbey-bar.co.uk",
    "website": "http://www.abbey-bar.co.uk",
    "location": {
      "latitude": 51.51241,
      "longitude": -0.0751462,
      "address": {
        "line1": "St Clare House",
        "line2": "30-33 Minories",
        "line3": "",
        "postcode": "EC3N 1DD",
        "city": "London",
        "country": "UK"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
require "json"
require "httparty"

restaurants = JSON.parse File.read('pretty-regex2.json')

restaurants.each do |restaurant|
  response = HTTParty.post("https://api.example/placeholder",
  {
    :body => restaurant.to_json,
    :headers => { "Content-Type" => "text", "Accept" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => "token example-placeholder" }
    })

  puts response.body
  puts response.code
  puts response.message
end
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this @Mircea - it worked for the first couple of records but then failed - probably a problem at the API side. Will run the code again and see what happens.

Comment: Do I need to build in a delay to stop it failing?

Comment: would recommend on printing the output for each attempt. It may be that the API is limiting you on how many requests you can perform or something else is happening - cannot tell unless I see what the error are